# Pandas merge near by entry

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas merge_asof not meeting expectation....example below:

```
left = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5, 10], 'left_val': ['b', 'c']})

right = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3, 7], 'right_val': [6, 7]})

pd.merge_asof(left, right, on='a', direction='nearest')
```

This gives:

```
      a left_val  right_val
0   5        b          6
1  10        c          7
```

My expectations:

```
      a left_val  right_val
0   5        b          6
1   5        b          7
2  10        c          7
```

given 3 and 7 are equidistant from 5...so my expectation.
Any way to achieve this?

EDIT: Anyway to achieve this in pandas like this other than as of.

Comment: asof picks the closest/nearest, not a range. you can have a look at the docs for more details. you probably have non-equi joins in mind, which is not what asof does

Comment: 3 is nearer than 7, so the algorithm picks the row for 3. a binary search could help. There isnt any existing function in Pandas yet for non equi joins

Comment: have a look at the docs to understand the rationale.

Comment: @sammywemmy is right but you can manually do that. Check my answer if it fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.merge` with `how='cross'` to create all combinations from left and right dataframes and compute distance between `a` and `a_right`.

```
out = pd.merge(left, right, how='cross', suffixes=('', '_right'))
out['dist'] = out['a'].sub(out['a_right']).abs()
```

At this point:

```
>>> out
    a left_val  a_right  right_val  dist
0   5        b        3          6     2  # dist == dist.min() / group 5
1   5        b        7          7     2  # dist == dist.min() / group 5
2  10        c        3          6     7  # dist > dist.min()  / group 10
3  10        c        7          7     3  # dist == dist.min() / group 10
```

Keep rows where `dist == dist.min()`:

```
>>> out.loc[out.groupby('a')['dist'].apply(lambda d: d == d.min()),
            ['a', 'left_val', 'right_val']]

    a left_val  right_val
0   5        b          6
1   5        b          7
3  10        c          7
```